# How can i make 'li' s width equal in the same column but different row, bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using angularJS and bootstrap. I don't want to use table so I am using div tags. I have a row for headers and there is a row for data. That row is dynamic, I mean it calls data from service using ng-repeat. My problem is the data cell width in headers row and data cell width in other rows are not equal like a table.Here some code example:

```css
.attributeHeaderList {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.attributeList {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.attributeHeaderList li, .attributeList li {
    border-right-style: inset;
    line-height: 35px;
}

.attributeHeaderList li:last-child, .attributeList li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

```
<div class="row" id="attrHeaders">
    <div class="col col-sm-7 col-md-8 col-lg-8" id="attrHeadersChild">
        <ul class="nav-justified attributeHeaderList">
            <li >Age</li>
            <li>Gender</li>
            <li>Weight</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div>

    <div class="col col-sm-7 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
        <ul class="nav-justified attributeList">
            <li>24</li>
            <li>m</li>
            <li>80</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the result. I want columns have same width. For good viewing please use EXPAND SNIPPET button. Thanks for any helps.

Comment: You can use bootstrap grid to achieve his.Do u know how?

Comment: Yes i know bootstrap grid. But can you give an example?

Comment: I answer you with working snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have working snippet:

```css
.attributeHeaderList {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.attributeList {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.attributeHeaderList li, .attributeList li {
    border-right-style: inset;
    line-height: 35px;
}

.attributeHeaderList li:last-child, .attributeList li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   
<div class="row" id="attrHeaders">
    <div class="col col-sm-7 col-md-8 col-lg-8" id="attrHeadersChild">
        <ul class="row list-inline attributeHeaderList">
            <li class="col-xs-4">Age</li>
            <li class="col-xs-4">Gender</li>
            <li class="col-xs-4">Weight</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-sm-7 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
        <ul class="row list-inline attributeList">
            <li class="col-xs-4">24</li>
            <li class="col-xs-4">m</li>
            <li class="col-xs-4">80</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is great.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Bootstrap grid columns in the lists..

```
<div class="row" id="attrHeaders">
        <div class="col col-sm-7 col-md-8 col-lg-8" id="attrHeadersChild">
            <ul class="row list-inline attributeHeaderList">
                <li class="col-xs-4">Age</li>
                <li class="col-xs-4">Gender</li>
                <li class="col-xs-4">Weight</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-sm-7 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
            <ul class="row list-inline attributeList">
                <li class="col-xs-4">24</li>
                <li class="col-xs-4">m</li>
                <li class="col-xs-4">80</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Also, don't use `nav-justified` as that will make the LI different widths depending on their content.

http://www.codeply.com/go/DMjvcwF648